# How can I throttle the body of a Future.traverse(myList) { l => Foo(l) } ?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8))
```

at the time but it seems like the code in my

```
Future.traverse(myList) { v =>
  barService.fooFuture(v)
}
```

seems to be going at max speed or threads resulting in rate limiting issues with a 3rd party api. barService has it's own ExecutionContext injected through guice as well. How would I throttle how quickly barService.fooFuture(v) is called?

Comment: What about passing the `ExecutionContext` explicitly? `barService.fooFuture(v)(ec)`

Comment: So to explain a little more, this code is run once on the off hours, takes a few minutes to finish. Normally that function doesn't need any slowing down during the day. Passing the ec explicitly to the function would require adding that as a parameter and complicating it for where it's used normally which doesn't seem right to do considering the issue is the one time script

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "throttle how quickly" ... You can always put `Thread.sleep(whatever)` before the call to `.fooFuture` ...